# How to control embedded devices remotely

Tags: networking, ssh, embedded

I'm working for a company providing a device for which we would like to provide web based access and control.

We currently embed a ts-7800 board in the device which runs linux.
This is provided with a static local ip address giving access on the lan.

I wish to make these devices viewable and controllable from anywhere in the world.
I would also prefer them to self configure using dhcp, similar to how skype communicates with its client software.

I am wondering if there is a way for the devices to open a connection to my server and then remain available for possible instructions, using some sort of reverse ssh tunneling process for example.

Could someone please let me know if this is possible or give me a prod in the right direction.

Mark

Comment: Yes, most microcontrollers  support TCP stacks including DHCP something and robust as the TS-7800 is not required unless you need that performance. There are many no-OS chips and support from Microchip, Atmel, ARM, etc...

Comment: I think [hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching) is what I was looking for, although the port number seems to be changing each time (might be a setting). Also the ts-7800 is being used for longeitivity (need about 10 years)

Comment: @Kenny:  The question details the OS and hardware used, the question is not about the appropriateness of the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible then you can add GPRS modem and access this embedded device remotely.

Comment: I believe my predecessor tried this but gave up on it due to difficulties with network providers abroad. A good option though, especially if you can get a static ip address, thanks

Comment: in embedded domain getting static ip is not viable. So the only solution is to go with GPRS but use it in optimize manner.

Answer (score 2):

MQTT (http://mqtt.org/) is a machine-to-machine (M2M)/"Internet of Things" connectivity protocol. It was designed as an extremely lightweight publish/subscribe messaging transport. It is useful for connections with remote locations where a small code footprint is required and/or network bandwidth is at a premium.

My-Devices.net (http://www.my-devices.net/) a web and cloud-based platform enabling secure remote access to the built-in web server of smart devices, using any web client running on a PC, server, smartphone or tablet.

Yaler (https://yaler.net/) provides a command line tool for Linux devices and libraries for other platforms to make your device accessible from anywhere with a Web browser or SSH. (Disclosure: I'm a founder)

Answer (score 0):

[This item](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1348) on remote monitoring and control using a Raspberry Pi which runs Linux may describe a suitable approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full requirements of your project, but the ts7800 is a beast and might be overkill. Do you need linux?

How about controlled via an SSL web page or ssh tunnel? You can do either one of those for $59 with an [SB70LC device from NetBurner](http://www.netburner.com/products/serial_to_ethernet/sb70lc.html). This would also meet your DHCP requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I need something which is going to last for ten years ideally so i'm prototyping with the ts7800 and linux. I have since come across www.yaler.org and reversehttp.net which I believe should handle the problem nicely